# Angular: Testing guards that return observables

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs, karma-runner

I am trying to test an auth guard that returns an observable, and makes a call to another function. My guard looks like this (lifted from Todd Motto. Cheers Todd):

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductSummaryLoadedGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private store: Store<fromProductStore.State>) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.checkStore().pipe(
      switchMap(() => of(true)),
      catchError(() => of(false))
    );
  }

  checkStore(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.pipe(select(fromProductStore.selectProductLoaded)).pipe(
      tap(loaded => {
        if (!loaded) {
          this.store.dispatch(new fromProductStore.LoadProductSummary());
        }
      }),
      filter(loaded => loaded),
      take(1)
    );
  }
}
```

I have put together the skeleton of the spec for this, and the extract causing the issue is this:

```
it('should return true when checkStore() returns true', () => {
  spyOn(guard, 'checkStore').and.returnValue(of(true));

  const result = guard.canActivate();
  expect(result).toBeObservable(of(true));
});
```

I run into this error in Karma when executing this spec:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
>      at Function.TestScheduler.parseMarbles (./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/testing/TestScheduler.js?:243:21)

What am I missing here? I don't want to go down the route of using marble testing for just this one method but if someone can suggest a way then I'd be happy to try it!

Comment: A complete shot in the dark here, but if you change your `expect` line to `result.subscribe(res => expect(res).toEqual(true))` does it work?  I'm wondering because the .toBeObservable() matcher is from the marble testing lib and perhaps there's an issue with their code.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing! Did you find a solution or workaround @serlingpa?

Comment: It's because `expectedObservable` from `toBeObservable(expectedObservable)` should be a `TestObservable` (`TestColdObservable | TestHotObservable`) which has a `marbles` property.
You need to use the `cold()` or `hot()` functions to create one.

https://medium.com/@bencabanes/marble-testing-observable-introduction-1f5ad39231c

Comment: @NickDarvey no idea what you're talking about :/  Could you write an answer and add some specific detail?

Answer (score 3):

The example [Effect testing](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing) code from NgRx show using toBeObservable thus:

```
const expected = hot('-------a', {
  a: {
    type: '[Customers API] Search Customers Success',
    customers: [...],
  },
});

expect(
  effects.searchCustomers$({
    debounce: 20,
    scheduler: getTestScheduler(),
  })
).toBeObservable(expected);
```

the `.toBeObservable()` is expecting a `TestHotObservable` or `TestColdObservable`, which have `marbles` properties.  I got here because I am getting an error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'marbles' of undefined` by using `.toBeObservable()` with no parameters.

If you want to do your testing with observables that aren't `TestXXXObservable` types, you'll have to subscribe to them and verify results within the subscription as [NgRx testing example](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing#with-observables) shows:

```
// create an actions stream and immediately dispatch a GET action
actions$ = of({ type: '[Customers Page] Get Customers' });

// mock the service to prevent an HTTP request
customersServiceSpy.getAllCustomers.and.returnValue(of([...]));

// subscribe to the Effect stream and verify it dispatches a SUCCESS action
effects.getAll$.subscribe(action => {
  expect(action).toEqual({
    type: '[Customers API] Get Customers Success',
    customers: [...],
  });
});
```

Comment: You sir are a genius! I was using of() instead of hot or cold. Thx a lot.

Comment: If I were a genius, I would have never hit the error and written this, but glad it helped someone :)